# how do RISC-V instructions change when executing them on a 64 bit architecture instead of 32 bit

Tags: assembly, riscv

When reading the RISC-V ISA manual, I came across some 32 bit instructions, but I cannot figure out what they would look like in 64 bit.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Short answer is the instructions look the same, they are the same size, same opcodes, same encodings, etc.. just operate on the 64-bit platform.  If you're looking for general information, just search a bit more. If you have a specific question you can't find an answer for, then ask it.